# Why the 500 when calling web service method?

Tags: c#, ajax, web-services

I'm getting a 500, [ArgumentException: Unknown web method GetFacilityInfo.
 Parameter name: methodName].  It looks like everything is in order; most of the results from googling the problem were people confused about whether to use static or not, but as you can see I am correctly NOT using a static method since it is an actual web service.

var data contents:

clientId: "DevClient"
facilityId: "2"

Web Service:

```
namespace Sentry.WebMethods
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [ToolboxItem(false)]
    [ScriptService]
    public class FacilityInfoService : WebService
    {
        [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public FacilityInfo GetFacilityInfo(string facilityId, string clientId)
        {
            try
            {
                var helper = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<EditCheckDataHelper>();
                var facility = helper.GetFacility(Convert.ToInt16(facilityId), clientId);
                return facility;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
                return new FacilityInfo();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Javascript call:

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        url: postUrl,
        dataType: "text",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: false,
        success: function (respScript) {
            if (xhr.status == 200) {
                return JSON.parse(respScript).d;
            }
        },
        error: function (xhrObj) {
            if (xhrObj.status > 0) {
                alert("[" + xhrObj.status + "] Failed to retrieve facility info.");
            }
        },
        complete: function () {
        }
    });
```

Comment: Server should have returned some text in addition to the 500. Use network sniffer to see it.

Comment: try to recreate your call in POSTMAN, then you can jiggle a little

Comment: There is nothing more useful being returned.  It is just the HTML for an ASP.NET error page with the exception noted in the post above.

Comment: If I try to hit the URL with ?WSDL, I get the following:  System.InvalidOperationException: GetFacilityInfo Web Service method name is not valid.  After a little more googling, someone had mentioned that they had the same problem, but it did not occur when he removed parameters from the method signature.  However, this is not the case for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that, since there was quite amazingly not an obvious way to add the web service .asmx file through Visual Studio (please enlighten me - Premium 2012), I had copy-pasted another .asmx file, and it was pointing to the wrong class in the mark-up.  (facepalm)